# implement Game States with MVC layout?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, libgdx, states

Hi I am creating a basic game and trying to implement MVC pattern with my code. I currently have:
**Model**
game object, clouds, boat water ect.

**world** 
This ties all the models together and defines the objects

**WorldRenderer**
This applies all textures to the objects

**GameScreen**
this handles user input, touch or keyboard.

My issue is how and where would i implement Game States?
I am assuming it would go into the GameScreen, but i have implemented the basic layout of the states ,READY ,RUNNING, PAUSED, NEXT_LVL, GAME_OVER,

But what i am finding that the when the state READY is presented the game is running in the background?

this is defined in the WorldRenderer, i.e the water lvl is rising up the screen in the back ground, but i want this to only happen when the game state switches to running.

how would i get the Gamestate to only initialise the the WorldRenderer when the Gamstate switches to the RUNNING STATE. I have applied the statement `renderer.render();` into the RUNNING statement but it still runs in the READY state.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Cheers

Daniel.

I am attaching the WorldRenderer, World, and GameScreen classes

```
GameScreen Class


    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;




    public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    enum State{
        READY,RUNNING,PAUSED,LEVEL_END,GAME_OVER
    }


    MainThing game;


    OrthographicCamera cam;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    Texture pauseMenu;
    TextureRegion pauseMenuR;

    Texture pauseBtn;

    Texture ready;
    TextureRegion readyR;

    private World world;
    private WorldRenderer renderer;

    public static State state = State.READY;


    public GameScreen(MainThing game){

        this.game = game;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(800,480);
        cam.position.set(800/2, 480/2, 0);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        state = State.READY;

        loadingTexture();

    }





    private void loadingTexture() {

        pauseBtn = Assets.manager.get("pause.png", Texture.class);

        pauseMenu = Assets.manager.get("resume-quit.png", Texture.class);
        pauseMenu.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        pauseMenuR = new TextureRegion(pauseMenu,0,0,375,256);

        ready = Assets.manager.get("ready.png",Texture.class);
        readyR = new TextureRegion(ready,0,0,256,105);
    }


    public static void setState(State newState){
        state = newState;
    }





    private void update(float delta) {

        switch (state) {
        case READY:
            updateReady();
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            updateRunning(delta);
            break;
        case PAUSED:
            updatePaused();
            break;
        case LEVEL_END:
            updateLevelEnd();
            break;
        case GAME_OVER:
            updateGameOver();
            break;
        }

    }



    private void updateReady() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            state = State.RUNNING;
        }

    }

    private void updateRunning(float delta) {

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
             WorldRenderer.cam.unproject(touchPos);
             Boat.position.x = touchPos.x - 1f / 2;
          }



        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {

        Boat.velocity.x = -Boat.SPEED * delta;
        }


        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {

            Boat.velocity.x = Boat.SPEED * delta;
          }
        else if(!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && !(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)))) {

            Boat.velocity.x = 0;
            }

          Boat.update(delta);

          if(Boat.position.x < 0) Boat.position.x = 0;
          if(Boat.position.x > WorldRenderer.cam.viewportWidth - 1f) Boat.position.x = WorldRenderer.cam.viewportWidth - 1f;


    }




    private void updatePaused() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void updateLevelEnd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void updateGameOver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void draw(float deltaTime) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render(deltaTime);
        cam.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.begin();

        switch (state) {
        case READY:
            presentReady();
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            presentRunning(deltaTime);
            break;
        case PAUSED:
            presentPaused();
            break;
        case LEVEL_END:
            presentLevelEnd();
            break;
        case GAME_OVER:
            presentGameOver();
            break;
        }
        batch.end();
    }




    private void presentReady() {
        batch.draw(readyR, cam.viewportWidth /2 - 375 /2    , cam.viewportHeight /2 - 256 /2,375,256);

    }





    private void presentRunning(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void presentPaused() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void presentLevelEnd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void presentGameOver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update(delta);
        draw(delta);



    }






    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        renderer.setSize(width,height);

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        world = new World();
        renderer = new WorldRenderer(world, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Assets.unload();


        Boat.dispose();
        Cloud.dispose();
        WorldRenderer.dispose();


    }



}
```

World Class

```
  package com.inspirednotion.thing;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;



public class World {

Boat boat;
Water water;
Cloud cloud;
long lastDropTime;
Array<Rain> raindrops = new Array<Rain>();


public Array<Rain> getRain(){
     return raindrops;

}

 Boat getBoat(){
    return boat;
}
public Water getWater(){
    return water;
}

public Cloud getCloud(){
    return cloud;
}


public World(){

    createWorld();
    spawnRaindrop();
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void createWorld() {
    boat = new Boat(new Vector2(WorldRenderer.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 - Boat.BOAT_WIDTH / 2, Water.position.y +11.3f ));
    cloud = new Cloud(new Vector2(WorldRenderer.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 - Cloud.CLOUD_WIDTH /2, 8));
    water = new Water(new Vector2(WorldRenderer.CAMERA_WIDTH /2 - Water.WATER_WIDTH/2, -11.3f));




}
void spawnRaindrop(){
raindrops.add( new Rain(new Vector2(MathUtils.random(cloud.position.x, cloud.position.x + Cloud.CLOUD_WIDTH ),cloud.position.y)));
lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

public static void dispose() {


}
}
```

WorldRenderer Class

```
public class WorldRenderer {

    private static World world;
    public static OrthographicCamera cam;

    ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

     static final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 20f;
    static final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 12f;

    static Texture cloudTexture;
    private TextureRegion cR;
    static Texture boatAniTex;
    TextureRegion[]                 boatFrames;
    Animation                       boatAnimation;
    TextureRegion                   boatCurrentFrame;
    static TextureRegion                   currentFrameBoat;
    TextureRegion[][]               tmpBoat;

    static Texture cloudBg;
    private TextureRegion cloudBgR;


    static Texture rainDrop;
    long lastDropTime;
    float lastDropT;


    private static Texture water;
    TextureRegion[]                 waveFrames;
    Animation                       waveAnimation;
    TextureRegion                   currentFrame;
    TextureRegion                   currentFrameWav;
    TextureRegion[][]               tmp;

    float stateTime = 0f; 

    private static SpriteBatch batch;

    static int width;
     static int height;

    public void setSize(int w, int h){
        WorldRenderer.width= w;
        WorldRenderer.height = h;
    }



    public WorldRenderer(World world, boolean debug){

        WorldRenderer.world = world;
        WorldRenderer.cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH ,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        WorldRenderer.cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH /2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT /2f, 0);
        WorldRenderer.cam.update();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        loadTextures();
        loadAnimations();




    }





    public void loadTextures(){
        boatAniTex = Assets.manager.get("bin.png", Texture.class);
        boatAniTex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        cloudTexture = Assets.manager.get("cloud.png", Texture.class);
        cloudTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        cR = new TextureRegion(cloudTexture,0,0,256,140);
        cloudBg = Assets.manager.get("cloudbg.png", Texture.class);
        cloudBg.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        cloudBgR = new TextureRegion(cloudBg,0,0,800,480);
        water = Assets.manager.get("wavey.png", Texture.class);
        water.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        rainDrop = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("RainDrop_sml.png"));
    }


    private void loadAnimations() {

        water.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        tmp = new TextureRegion(water).split(800,480);                                
        waveFrames = new TextureRegion[14];
        for (int x = 0, index = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++, index++) {
               waveFrames[index] = tmp[x][y];
            }
         }

        waveAnimation = new Animation(0.14f, waveFrames); 

        //************************

boatAniTex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        tmpBoat = new TextureRegion(boatAniTex).split(64,64);                                
        boatFrames = new TextureRegion[7];
        for (int x = 0, indexed = 0; x < 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++, indexed++) {
               boatFrames[indexed] = tmpBoat[x][y];
            }
         }

        boatAnimation = new Animation(0.2f, boatFrames); 

    }


    public void render(float delta){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();  
        currentFrameWav = waveAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime += delta, true);
        currentFrameBoat = boatAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime += delta, true);
        batch.begin();


        batch.disableBlending();
        drawBackGround();
        batch.enableBlending();
        drawBoat();

        drawWater(delta);
        drawCloud();


        batch.end();
        drawRain();
    }





    private void drawRain() {
        batch.begin();
        for(  Rain bounds: world.raindrops) {
             batch.draw(rainDrop, bounds.position.x ,  bounds.position.y,.2f,.2f);

        }
        batch.end();
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - world.lastDropTime >  500000000) world.spawnRaindrop();




        Iterator<Rain> iter = world.raindrops.iterator();
          while(iter.hasNext()) {
             Rain raindrop = iter.next();
             raindrop.position.y -=2f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(raindrop.position.y < Water.position.y  ) {
                System.out.println("water is hit");
                iter.remove();
            }
          }
    }



    private void drawWater(float delta) {
        batch.draw(currentFrameWav, Water.position.x , Water.position.y ,Water.WATER_WIDTH , Water.WATER_HEIGHT );
        if (Water.position.y < -4f){
            Water.position.y += .1 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            Boat.position.y += .1 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }
    }



    private void drawBackGround() {

        batch.draw(cloudBgR, 0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    }



    private void drawCloud(){
        Cloud cloud = world.getCloud();
         batch.draw(cR,cloud.position.x ,cloud.position.y ,Cloud.CLOUD_WIDTH , Cloud.CLOUD_HEIGHT );
    }


    private void drawBoat(){
        world.getBoat();
         batch.draw(currentFrameBoat, Boat.position.x , Water.position.y +11.3f,Boat.BOAT_WIDTH , Boat.BOAT_HEIGHT );
    }








    private void drawDebug(){
        debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);

        Cloud cloud = world.getCloud();
        Rectangle rect =  cloud.bounds;
        float x1 = cloud.position.x + rect.x;
        float y1 = cloud.position.y + rect.y;
        debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1,0,0,1));
        debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);

        Boat boat = world.getBoat();
        Rectangle rec =  boat.bounds;
        float xx1 = Boat.position.x + rec.x;
        float yx1 = Boat.position.y + rec.y;
        debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1,1,0,1));
        debugRenderer.rect(xx1, yx1, rec.width, rec.height);

        debugRenderer.end();
    }




public static   void dispose(){
    cloudTexture.dispose();
    water.dispose();
    boatAniTex.dispose();
    rainDrop.dispose();
    cloudBg.dispose();
    batch.dispose();

}
}
```

please excuse the messy code.. in process of cleaning and debugging the issues..

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line up front: Your `GameScreen` is in `READY` state, but your `WorldRenderer` doesn't know that and goes on its merry way. You need to make sure that your `WorldRenderer` has states that map to the `GameScreen` states.

Your call to `renderer.render(deltaTime)` in `GameScreen.draw()` is the culprit. It's updating the positions of things all the time, regardless of the state in `GameScreen`.

Assuming the desired effect is to have the game drawn in the background, but with play not started -

1. Add a state enum to `WorldRenderer` that is at least `WAITING` and `PLAYING`, with a field of this enum type. Make sure there's a public method created in `WorldRenderer` that will allow `GameScreen` to set this value.
2. When `GameScreen` creates `WorldRenderer`, make sure to call and set the `WorldRenderer` state to `WAITING`.
3. When `GameScreen` transitions to a playing state, call and set the `WorldRenderer` state to `PLAYING`.
4. In `WorldRenderer`, carefully define what needs to be done in a `WAITING` state, a `PLAYING` state, and in both. In this case, you don't want the water to rise, so don't change the water and boat's height if you are in `WAITING` state.